# Angular HTML Binding is not working when we removed HostListener

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular2-template

to make change detection lesser, we replace hostlistener with from event from RXJS and runoutside of angular.

this is how my angular code looks like

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.windowKeyDown();
    // this.subject$ = this.subject.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}

  //@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log('handle key fired');
    this.keypressed = event.key;
    this.iskeyPressed = true;
  }

  windowKeyDown() {
    console.log('windowKeyDown');
    fromEvent(window, 'keydown')
      .pipe(this.outsideZone(this._ngZone))
      .subscribe(event => this.handleKeyboardEvent(<KeyboardEvent>event));
  }

  outsideZone<T>(zone: NgZone) {
    return function(source: Observable<T>) {
      return new Observable(observer => {
        let sub: Subscription;
        zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
          sub = source.subscribe(observer);
        });

        return sub;
      });
    };
  }
```

and HTML binding is :

```
<h2>keypressed: {{keypressed}}</h2>
<h2>iskeyPressed: {{iskeyPressed}}</h2>
```

in this binding variable it self not updating now, can you please guide what's wrong with my code?

minimum step to repro : https://stackblitz.com/edit/keypress-example-vu3mej?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting the ChangeDetectionStrategy for this component to OnPush. You can read more about it [here](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4). Do not put any logic in this component for which you want automatic change detection as changedetection is disabled for the component as a whole.

Below is a code sample that shows how you can subscribe to the keyboard events directly from the template (using the async pipe).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-detection-strategy-onpush-g6mjkr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="keyboard$ | async as keyBoard">
      <h2>keypressed: {{ keyBoard.keypressed }}</h2>
      <h2>iskeyPressed: {{ keyBoard.iskeyPressed }}</h2>
    </ng-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: [],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  keyboard$: Observable<{ keypressed: any; iskeyPressed: boolean }>;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('bla')
    this.keyboard$ = fromEvent(window, 'keydown').pipe(
      map(event => ({ keypressed: event.key, iskeyPressed: true })),
      startWith({keypressed: null, iskeyPressed: null})
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try this solution and accept the answer.